# Toggle rails boolean using link_to with validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, boolean

I have an answer model which has a "correct" boolean column, so much like stackoverflow an answer can be marked as correct. I have the following controller code which uses a toggle! method to toggle the "correct" boolean value, however, toggle! skips all validations, which I want to avoid.

How can I amend my code so that I avoid using toggle! in the controller to allow for validations and still use a single button to toggle the boolean value?

routes.rb

```
resources :answers do 
    member { put :correct }
  end

correct_answer PUT    /answers/:id/correct(.:format)                 answers#correct
```

answers_controller.rb

```
 def correct 
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
    if @answer.toggle!(:correct)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @answer, notice: "Submitted" }
      format.js
      end
    end
```

_answer.html.erb

```
<div id="correct_answer_<%= answer.id %>" class="<%= answer.correct == true ? 'green-tick' : 'default-tick' %>">
    <% if answer.question.user == current_user %>
       <%= link_to "✓", correct_answer_path(answer), id: "tick", class: "correct_#{answer.id}", remote: true, method: :put %>
    <% else %>
       <% if answer.correct == true %>
         <div id="tick", class='correct_<% answer.id %>'> ✓</div>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [source code](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Base/toggle!) shows

```
def toggle!(attribute)
  toggle(attribute).update_attribute(attribute, self[attribute])
end
```

And `update_attribute` does not run validations, ie. `save(false)`.

You could override it using `update_attributes` which does run validations.
Like this

```
def toggle!(attribute)
  toggle(attribute).update_attributes({attribute => self[attribute]})
end
```